# Define custom annotation within another custom annotation with default value

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to declare custom annotation in following way:

```
Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface InnerAnnotation {

}

Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface OuterAnnotation {
  public String default "";
  public InnerAnnotation innerAnnotation(); //here I wanted to do "public InnerAnnotation innerAnnotation() default {some default value}"
}

I wanted to use it in a way:
class first{
  @OuterAnnotation(value = "new") //wanted to declare something like this without need to define innerAnnotation
  public void func(){
  }
}
```

I wanted to assign some default value to inner annotation usage(so that I don't have to provide any mandatory value while using it), but some how I am not able to do that as compiler asks for compile time constant for this.Can any please suggest how to use inner annotation with any default value ?

Comment: Let me know the scenario or how you are going to use this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for what you what is as follows:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface OuterAnnotation {
    public String default "";
    public InnerAnnotation innerAnnotation() default @InnerAnnotation(); //this does the trick;  
}
```